# imap send email particular date python

Tags: python, imap

I have a project with IMAP, python.

I want to read Gmail with IMAP, 
and I want to send it on a particular date and time.
Is it possible?

I know send email in IMAP or read someone's email with IMAP.

But I don't know that sending email on a particular date and time.

Comment: IMAP is not for sending mail, for that you want SMTP.

Comment: Then, can I send email with SMTP particular date and time?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is an SMTP extension called [future release](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4865), which is only rarely implemented. You can tell gmail doesn support that:

```
$ telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
Trying 2a00:1450:400c:c0b::6c...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP p104sm12110308wrc.66 - gsmtp
ehlo asdf
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2001:4d88:100c:...
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
```

No FUTURERELEASE in the list. It would look like this (from another server):

```
250-FUTURERELEASE 406682791 2030-04-04T08:00:00Z
```

You may be able to purchase this as a service form e.g. mailgun/sendgrid/whathaveyou. And of course it's easy to implement on any unix server.